# Conexión de NodeJS a SQL Server: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS

Tags: nodejs, mssql

En mi problema que tengo es que en consola me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> PS C:\Users\abrah\OneDrive\Escritorio\ControlEscolarDB> node index.js
> Escuchando en puerto 8080
> Error: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\abrah\OneDrive\Escritorio\ControlEscolarDB\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1404:28)
> at C:\Users\abrah\OneDrive\Escritorio\ControlEscolarDB\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1185:14
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> isTransient: undefined
> }

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: ¿`ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS` que es?, ¿apunta algún lado? Si tu DDBB está en local prueba a poner `127.0.0.1` y si pretendes usar el nombre especificado tendras que añadirlo al archivo hosts de tu equipo. Por otro lado, ¿Está el servicio activo?

Comment: Tu pregunta es acerca de NodeJS y SQL Server, no de Visual Studio Code (que no es lo mismo que Visual Studio, por cierto). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, ¿ya investigaste qué significa ENOTFOUND?

Comment: estas seguro que la instruccion `node index.js Escuchando en puerto 8080` es correcta?

Comment: ABRAHAMSQLEXPRESS es el sever